# How to generate this permutation?

Tags: python-3.x

This is the numeric permutation I would like to generate --> 1,12,21,123,132,213,... 987654321.
I've made so many attempts but honestly I don't know where to start. I've tried using for loops, lists and permutations but it didn't work.
So I've tried this:

```
from itertools import permutations
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for x in list:
    permutations(list,x)
    list2 = list(permutations(list))
    print(list2)
```

The problem is not how to generate the permutation but to manage the increment of the digits.

Best regards and thank you all!

Comment: It's a real bad idea to name a variable `list`, given that it is a reserved keyword in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `itertools.permutations` returns permutations of all the same length (controlled by the `r` parameter, or the length of the iterable if `r` is `None`.)  Based on that, the key is to recognize that what you are *actually* looking for is **the union of multiple sets of permutations**.

Here's one way we could get that:

```
from itertools import permutations
digits = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
result = []
for result_size in range(1, len(digits) + 1):
    digits_slice = digits[:result_size]
    result.extend(permutations(digits_slice))
print(result)
# [(1,), (1, 2), (2, 1), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4, 3), ...]
```

Note: You should never use `list` as a variable name, because it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) type.  I renamed `list` to `digits` to avoid this problem.

If you want the items in the `result` list to be `int`s instead of `tuple`s, you can add:

```
result = [int(''.join(str(i) for i in tup)) for tup in result]
print(result)
# [1, 12, 21, 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321, 1234, 1243, ...]
```

Comment: What if I want to make an infinite list of premutations (1,12,21,...,12345678910,...)?

Comment: With a while loop and an ever increasing counter but you'll eventually run out of memory

Comment: You can wrap this in a generator function that `yield`s each permutation in turn.  You'll have to change the `for` loop to a `while True` loop, and you'll have to dynamically adjust the `digits` list at each iteration of the loop.  But overall it would be very similar.

Comment: `from itertools import permutations

r = []

def make_inf_sequence():
    x = 0
    while True:
        yield x
        x = x + 1
        digits = []
        digits = make_inf_sequence()
        for result_size in range(1, len(digits) + 1):
            digits_slice = digits[:result_size]
            r.extend(permutations(digits_slice))


r2 = [str(''.join(str(i) for i in tup)) for tup in r]
print(r2)`                                                                                                                                                            Like That?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to shadow python keywords.
You could try something like this:

```
from itertools import permutations
lst = [str(i) for i in range(10)]

for i in range(1,len(lst)+1):
    sub_list = lst[0:i]
    g = ("".join(perm) for perm in permutations(sub_list))
    # print(list(g))
```

Feel free to uncomment the print statement.